# Receiving Bluetooth Advertisement packets longer than specification max

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm running an android app (custom) that scans for nearby Bluetooth low energy devices, and I am noticing that some devices have longer advertised packets than specifications provision for. The scanning device is a Nexus 5 running Android 6.0.

I am using the following line on a ScanResult object `result.getScanRecord().getBytes();` to get the byte array

I know that the ScanRecord's byte array is actually constructed of the advertised data (mac address not included) and the scan response, so I expect 31 bytes each for a total of 62 bytes in the array. This is the size of the total array that I receive, but it looks like the advertised data makes it into the response portion of the array. The format follows the specification, where the first byte of a GAP is the length, next byte is GAP type, and next length-1 bytes is data.

But with this format, the devices in question have data fields that extend over into the response portion. Here's an example of the array in hex, with each GAP on a different line:

```
02 01 06  (flags)
0D FF DF 00 57 30 46 30 30 33 43 45 56 5A (manufacturer specific data)
11 07 6D 69 73 66 69 74 A6 34 4A 7D 7F 95 01(<-expected end of advertise) 00 DA 3D (UUID, 128-bit)
07 09 46 6F 73 73 69 6C   (device name)
03 03 12 18   (UUID, 16-bit)
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 (leftover bytes)
```

I don't really care about the scan response data, but I am confused as to how a BLE device could send advertisement packets larger than 31 bytes if it is on 4.2 specification (I know Bluetooth 5 allows larger packets, but the manufacturer states it uses 4.2). I can also see the name of the device showing as it should, but in the response portion.

Would anyone know why this is the case here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably those devices simply don't follow the specification (which requires an entry not to cross the packet boundaries). So your device might send

```
02 01 06 0D FF DF 00 57 30 46 30 30 33 43 45 56 5A 11 07 6D 69 73 66 69 74 A6 34 4A 7D 7F 95
```

as the Advertising Data and

```
01 00 DA 3D 07 09 46 6F 73 73 69 6C 03 03 12 18
```

as the Scan Response Data. You can see for example in the HCI log if this is correct. If it is so, you should complain to the manufacturer of that BLE device.

Comment: I can see where that may be the case, but then the first part of the response has a GAP type that doesn't actually exist, and then the following GAP would have a length far higher than the max size of an advertised packet on this specification. The HCI log should be on the scanning device, correct? I should probably take a look at that